# Why am I getting IOException : "Cannot run program ./shellScript.sh error = 2, No such file or directory in Java?

Tags: java, shell, command-line

The following Main.java code simply tries to simulate the following linux command:

```
cd /dir1/dir2
./shellScript.sh
```

The program below works only if the executable Main.jar sits *within* /dir1/dir2, not outside of /dir1/dir2.  How do I modify the program below so that Main.jar can sit anywhere on the file system?

```
public class Main {

    public static String runCmdLineProcess(String commandStr){
        String returnVal = "";
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        
        try {
            Process p = r.exec(commandStr);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = ""; 
            
            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null){
                returnVal += line + "\n";
            }

        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return returnVal;
    }

    public static void runProcessBuilder(String scriptPath){

        String[] cmd = {scriptPath};
        try {
            runCmdLineProcess("cd /dir1/dir2");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        runProcessBuilder("./shellScript.sh"); // <-- works if I run from inside "/dir1/dir2".  
                                               //But if I'm outside "dir2", get an error message 
                                               // saying "Cannot run program "./shellScript.sh": error = 2, No such file or directory
    }

}
```

Comment: There is an overloaded `exec` that lets you specify the working directory.

Comment: Likely issues: (1) you're running two processes, so 'cd' in one cannot affect the other, (2) 'cd' is not a separate executable anyway, it's a shell built-in.   But as the other comment says, it's the wrong way to go about it anyway.

Comment: String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash" , "-c",  "cd  /zookeeper/bin" + "./zkCli.sh"};
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
            pr.waitFor();

            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
               System.out.println(line);
            }
 whats wrog in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ProcessBuilder` to launch or one of the overloads of `exec`. You need to specify the pathname to the script and pass the same pathname as the current directory to run the script in:

```
File pwd = new File("/dir1/dir2");
String shell = new File(pwd, "shellScript.sh").toString();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(shell);
// No STDERR => merge to STDOUT - or call redirectError(File)
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
// Set CWD for the script
pb.directory(pwd);

Process p = pb.start();

// Move STDOUT to the output stream (or original code to save as String)
try(var stdo = p.getInputStream()) {
    stdo.transferTo(stdout);
}

int rc = p.waitFor();
```